# How to handle refresh token with Firebase in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I'm trying to implement firebase as Auth mechanism in my Ionic 4 app.
I'm using this code to let the user signIn with email and password:

```
    loginUser(value){
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
     firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
     .then(
       res => resolve(res),
       err => reject(err))
   })
  }
```

Since Firebase works with accessToken that expires after 1 hour of the creation and with refreshToken to refresh the first one, I'm not sure how to move on; I mean should I save both accessToken and refreshToken in my database? How to refresh the token? Is this operation done automatically or should I do something? I'm using also a JavaEE server, which detect if the user is correctly logged with Firebase, by passing the accessToken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I save both accessToken and refreshToken in my database?

Instead of persisting the tokens yourself, tell Firebase where to persist the authentication information with [`Auth.setPersistence()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#set-persistence). For example:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(fire.localPersistence())
```

Be sure to test if this is even needed though, as on most environments Firebase will automatically determine where to persist the authentication state.

---

> How to refresh the token? Is this operation done automatically or should I do something?

The ID token is automatically refreshed by the Firebase SDK, about 55 minutes after it was created.

Comment: Thank you! Where should I add this line of code in the app? By the way where Can I find a full working example with the latest version to implement also authentication with Facebook and Google?

Comment: As said, you may not have to call this API at all. If you end up having to call it, do that before you use any other APIs on the `firebase.auth()` instance.

Comment: Good! By the way I just need to get accessToken from the firebase instance and send it to the server? Also could you please add more lines of code of how to get the currentUser in different pages?

Comment: Get the user in a different page (so after a reload), probably means you need an auth state listener. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user To verify the user's state on a server, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens